# How to implement polling with backpressure in RXJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I want to poll a HTTP API that can be slow to answer, so I don't want to make multiple calls to this API at the same time.

An example of what I want to do could be:

```
const interval = Rx.Observable.interval(250).take(5); // Poll every 250ms

function simulateMaybeSlowHttpCall() {
  return interval.delay(500).take(1); // The service takes 500ms to answer
}

 interval
   .mergeMap(val =>simulateMaybeSlowHttpCall().map(x => val), 1) // max concurrent is 1
   .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Here, this code will display 
1
2
3
4
5

But I don't want to do  useless call. 
The above code runs for 250*5 = 1250 ms, 1 call take 500ms, so I would like to display:

1 
3
5

So my question is: when setting concurrent to `1` (or any other values), how can I discard all the call not done immediately ?

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zra3zxhs/63/

Comment: It sounds like a situation in which you should use [`exhaustMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-exhaustMap) instead of `mergeMap`.

Comment: It seems to do what I want. Can you post that as an answer, that way I will mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `mergeMap` with a concurrency of one is equivalent to `concatMap`. In fact, that's how [`concatMap` is implemented](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.8/src/operators/concatMap.ts#L69-L72). That's why each interval in your example effects a HTTP request: they are queued.

If you wish to avoid initiating or queuing a HTTP request whilst one is pending, you could use [`exhaustMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-exhaustMap):

```
interval
  .exhaustMap(val => simulateMaybeSlowHttpCall().map(x => val))
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

When `exhaustMap` is used, any `next` notifications that it receives are ignored until the inner observable (the HTTP request) completes.